# Adding a bootstrap attribute to cells in a DataTables.js column

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to add an attribute to the first column in my debatable so I just add a class in the `columns[]` setting called popperup.

However for the bootstrap popover to work I need to add the attribute `"tabindex":"0"`

This can be done with `$(".popperup").attr({"tabindex":"0"})`

however this only adds it to the first entries that load 10 in my datatable which then allows the popover to work the problem is when you click the next paginate button or numbered buttons it will not work as the `tabindex:0` is missing

```
I have tried using

$("#Ttable3").on('page.dt', function() {

        console.log("here")

        $(".popperup").attr({"tabindex":"0"})

    });
```

This only works once you have gone to the next page and then go back again. so you click next page or go to page 2/3/4 etc nothing happens. you go back to page 1 then back to page 2/3/4 and it will work

how can I get it so `"tabindex":"0"` is on every cell in a column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spend hours working on an issue and fix it the moment you post it on Stackoverflow

I needed to use `draw.dt` in the on call.

so this

```
$("#Ttable3").on('page.dt', function() {

    console.log("here")

    $(".popperup").attr({"tabindex":"0"})

});
```

becomes this

```
$("#Ttable3").on('draw.dt', function() {

    console.log("here")

    $(".popperup").attr({"tabindex":"0"})

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have defined your DataTable and assigned it to a variable...

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
  // your options here
} );
```

Then you can use the following to iterate over every node in the first column, using the `table` reference you defined:

```
var selectedCol = table.column(0).nodes();
for (var i = 0; i < selectedCol.length; i++) {
  $(selectedCol).attr({ "tabindex": "0" })
}
```